# After removing the development app from the connected apps in the Fit app, Fitness data could be obtained

Tags: android, google-fit, google-healthcare-api

[procedure]

1. OAuth account & permission approved. (in developing app)
2. in Google Fit App, remove developing app from "connected apps".
3. access sleep, weight and etc..., read health data. and succeeded (in developing app)

In step3, permissions of each fitness were permitted,
I hope that permissions were not permitted and cannot succeeded read date in step3.

What happened.
and Can I listen to removed my app from "connected apps".

[environment]
phone: Pixel 4a
OS: Android11

Comment: The documentation didn't mention what events will token expire. I'd suggest you try again step#3 after an hour If you can still read data after removing it from connected apps.

Comment: @ilovesyntax
Thanks for the comment.
I would like to know where to find the information that the TOKEN expires in 1 hour?

Comment: About an hour and a half later, "getToken() -> NEED_REMOTE_CONSENT.

Is there an API or other way to get the latest token instead of waiting for it to expire?

Comment: 1 hour token https://developers.google.com/fit/rest/v1/get-started#use_curl_to_access_the_fit_rest_api